# It seems that my MacBook Pro is on Acid. What’s going on here?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

My MacBook Pro 2017 first wouldn’t wake up (black screen) and then boot to this. Is this a hardware or software issue? What is going on?

[image]

Comment: Very acid indeed. It looks like a hardware issue though.

Comment: Is it plugged into a display? If it is connected to a second screen, maybe the display's connection cable is causing it.

Comment: No it is not. A restart also resolved the issue. But not really reassuring that this could happen again any time. I use my machine for work as a freelancer and every time I have to send it in for repairs costs me serious money (at least two days without pay, renting a replacement, the actual repair). I already replaced the screen some months ago because it just stopped working. If I didn't build apps I would have switched to a regular laptop with linux. Apple sucks big time nowadays.

Comment: Did you get the display replaced at Apple with an official spare part, or do you have a third-party display component installed?

Comment: Officially through apple. It was one of the cases where the cable was too short and would rip at some point.

Comment: Then I would definitely contact Apple support with this image. As the display replacement was done officially, you should have a renewed warranty on the display, so depending on when it was done, this could be covered. I would talk to their business support about having a replacement made available free of charge in the mean while, as you can indicate a business need and cost. I can't say if that is possible for you, but they have done that for me previously.

Comment: Weir thing: It booted for some time just to a black screen. Now it is working again. Not so sure if this really is a hardware issue.

Comment: nah.  Points to a hardware issue. Heat related.  Try safe boot. hold down shift key then boot.

Comment: I went to my Apple Store. They looked at it and said I have to replace the display. For 600 EUR. And since you only get a 3 month warranty for replacement parts it does not matter that they had to do it only 8 months ago. I was also within the warranty period, but since a company bought the device consumer law doesn't apply. So yeah, fuck me!